# dropdownlist not fetching values from table on OnSelectedIndexChanged

Tags: c#, asp.net

am trying to fetch values from database table on dropdownlist value change and display them in textbox. While selecting any value from the dropdownlist the page is refreshing but no values are displaying in the textbox and following are the codes:

Default.aspx

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
    <asp:ListItem Text="<Select Subject>" Value="0" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
 protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ddl2value = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();
        // fillDropdown3(ddl3, ddl2value);
        SqlConnection objConn2 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand objCmd2;
        SqlDataReader objRdr2;
        //  String strCmd2;
        objConn2.Open();




        objCmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT code, rank, address FROM agen_mast WHERE name = " +
        "'" + ddl2value.ToString() + "'", objConn2);
        objRdr2 = objCmd2.ExecuteReader();



        while (objRdr2.Read())
        {

            TextBox9.Text = (string)objRdr2["code"].ToString();
            TextBox8.Text = (string)objRdr2["address"].ToString().ToUpper();
            TextBox10.Text = (string)objRdr2["rank"].ToString().ToUpper();
        }

        objRdr2.Close();
        objConn2.Close();
     //   Response.Write(ddl2value.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Its been a while I looked at asp.net. however if I remember it correct,  it should be Selected Text shall have the selected value. Additionally,  debug and see what value are you placing in where clause after selection change and ensure you have at least one matching column value in table.

Comment: There is only 1 element in `DropDownList1` right? If there is only 1 element then the index actually does not change when you click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(DropDownList1.SelectedValue !="-1"){
        string ddl2value = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();
        SqlConnection objConn2 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand objCmd2;
        SqlDataReader objRdr2;
        objConn2.Open();

        objCmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT code, rank, address FROM agen_mast WHERE name = " +
        "'" + ddl2value + "'", objConn2);
        objRdr2 = objCmd2.ExecuteReader();

        while (objRdr2.Read())
        {

            TextBox9.Text = (string)objRdr2["code"].ToString();
            TextBox8.Text = (string)objRdr2["address"].ToString().ToUpper();
            TextBox10.Text = (string)objRdr2["rank"].ToString().ToUpper();
        }

        objRdr2.Close();
        objConn2.Close();
        }
    }
```

And add a dummy `ListItem` with `Value` `-1` as the first item in the `DropDownList1` in the `.aspx` side. By the way, make sure you are sending the correct parameter to `SqlCommand`. Right now you are looking for a record with `Name` = `0`. Also, `ddl2Value` is already of type `string` so you don't need to call `ToString()` inside `SqlCommand`